# Trying to execute an imported Async function but the function is not behaving asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I am using React to build a website.  I have imported an asynchronous function to execute when I press a button.  However, the function is not working asynchronously and I really don't understand why.

interact.js:

```
export const getNFT = async () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('getNFT code execute');
    return nft;
  }, 2000);
};

const nft = {
tokenURI: 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmdxQFWzBJmtSvrJXp75UNUaoVMDH49g43WsL1YEyb',
imageURL: 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmeMTHnqdfpUcRVJBRJ4GQ2XHU2ruVrdJqZhLz',
ID: '212'
};
```

Main.js

```
import {
  getNFT
} from 'interact.js';


// This function is executed when a user clicks on a button
let getAllocatedNFT = async () => {
try {
  let response = await getNFT();
  console.log('response from server:: '+response);
}catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}
};
```

console:

```
response from server:: undefined
getNFT code execute // This is executed correctly after 2 seconds
```

Comment: In interact.js, where do you get nft that you return. Didn't get your question

Comment: Because getNFT isn't returning anything (the setTimeout does, but the function execution is ended by that time). You should create and return a Promise (inside getNFT and outside setTimeout) and resolve that promise from inside the setTimeout. This way the program has something to wait for

Comment: @S.Bonet sorry I had omitted the object nft which I have now added to the code above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return promise which will resolve your webAPI(setTimeout)
Please use like below:

```
  const getNFT = async () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("getNFT code execute")
        resolve(true)
      }, 2000)
    );
  };
```

Comment: @Vishai Nai, I have updated by code to include the nft object which I had forgotten to add

Comment: than you can pass that nft object into resolve(nft) like this and in response you will get that

Comment: @johnDoe also you can pass like below
resolve(JSON.stringify(nft))

and in below response you can parse that using JSON.parse(response)